# get parameter input from website, run python script and get output to server

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'd like to preface this by saying that I have ZERO javascript or flask knowledge.

Basically, I have made an html interface from which I am retrieving some user input. I would like to use this input as a parameter in a python function, run this function and then somehow retrieve the output of this function (which is a string btw) to display it on the website.

Here is my code (which obviously doesn't work):

python:

```
import get_response

app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/rep_bot',methods=['GET','POST'])
def bot_rep_py():
    outputpy=get_response(request.data)
    return render_template("output.html",output=outputpy)
```

the javascript function that I want to perform the sending and retrieving of information:

```
function bot_rep_js(input) {
  $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/rep_bot", {
    js_input:input
  });

  return console.log(data)
}
```

I have tried a few other things that didn't work anyway so I'm not gonna write them here so as not to hurt your eyes anymore.
If anyone would be so kind as to show and explain to me what I have to change in order for my code to behave the way I want it to I'd be very grateful.

Comment: first you have to learn JavaScript - or maybe rather jQuery which you use in code. `$.post` should have option to assign function which it will run when it get response from flask. And this function should replace elements in HTML. But for this it may be simpler to send output as JSON data without HTML, and inside JavaScript put it in correct place in HTML

Comment: if you tried few other things then you should describe it in question. This way we know what doesn't work for you and we don't have to suggests these methods. OR we can explain what was wrong in these methods.

Comment: see jQuery documentation for [post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and see option `success` which expect function and it send data from flask to this function.

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` has option to assign function which will be executed when it get response. And inside this function you should get data and use it to (re)place it in HTML.

```js
  $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/rep_bot",
         {js_input: input},
         function(data){console.log(data);}
  )
```

---

Minimal working example

`$.post` sends POST data with `"Hi"` to `flask` and `flask` sends back JSON data with answer `"Hello World!"` which `$.post` gets in assigned function and it puts this answer in `<div>`

I used `render_template_string` instead of `render_template` so all data are in one file and everyone can simply copy and run it.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string, jsonify

app= Flask(__name__)

def get_response(data):
    print('data:', data)  # "Hi"
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route('/rep_bot', methods=['GET','POST'])
def bot_rep_py():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        input_text  = request.form["js_input"]
        print('input_text :', input_text)
        
        output_text = get_response(input_text)
        print('output_text:', output_text)
        
        return jsonify({'answer': output_text})
    else:
        return "???"
    
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button>Send "Hi"</button>

<div id="answer"></div>

<script>
$(function(){

console.log("ready 1");

function bot_rep_js(input) {
  console.log(input)
  $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/rep_bot",
         {js_input: "Hi"},
         function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $("#answer").text(data.answer);
         },
        );
}

$("button").click(bot_rep_js);

console.log("ready 2");

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
''')

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run(debug=True)#, use_reloader=False)
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same without `jQuery` using standard `fetch()` and `.then()` to execute function when it gets response from server.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string, jsonify

app= Flask(__name__)

def get_response(data):
    print('data:', data)  # "Hi"
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route('/rep_bot', methods=['GET','POST'])
def bot_rep_py():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        input_text  = request.form["js_input"]
        print('input_text :', input_text)
        
        output_text = get_response(input_text)
        print('output_text:', output_text)
        
        return jsonify({'answer': output_text})
    else:
        return "???"
    
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<script>
// function `bot_rep_js` has to be before `onclick="bot_rep_js()"`

console.log("ready 1");

function bot_rep_js(input) {
  console.log("input: " + input)
  
  // create form and add file
  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("js_input", "Hi");

  // create AJAX connection
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/rep_bot", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formdata,
    //headers: {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}  // makes only problem
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.json();   // get JSON from response
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    document.querySelector("#answer").innerText = data.answer;
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Fetch problem: " + err.message);
  });
}

console.log("ready 2");

</script>

<button onclick="bot_rep_js()">Send "Hi"</button>

<div id="answer"></div>

</body>
</html>
''')

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    app.run(debug=True)#, use_reloader=False)
```

`fetch()` could send data as JSON but I send as FORM to make it similar to previous code.

Comment: unfortunately my code still doesn't work, now it looks something like this: `function bot_rep_js(input) {
  $.post("/rep_bot", 
  {js_input:input},
  function(data){return data.answer;},
  json
  );

}` for the JS function and my flask function is: `@app.route('/rep_bot',methods=['GET','POST'])
def bot_rep_py():
    if request.method=='POST':
        input_text=request.form["js_input"]

        output_text=get_response(input_text)
        return jsonify({'answer':output_text})
    else:
        return "erreur pas POST"` From what i gather the server never receives the post req

Comment: you should use `DevTool` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` (tab `Console`) to see JavaScript errors. As for me `$.post` need full URL `http://..../rep_bot`. You should also run flask in console to see error messages. And you could use `print()` to see what you get in variables. Shortly: you have to use `print()` in Python and `console.log()` in JavaScript to debug code

Comment: if you use option `json` in `$.post` then in flask you have to use `request.json` instead of `request.form`. But I'm not sure if in `$.post` it can be variable `json` - it may have to be string `"json"`. And `$.post` may need `JSON.stringify({js_input: "Hi"}),` to send it as  JSON